# Where to download latest Lucene.NET source zip?

Tags: lucene.net

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/  has it in svn tree format. I need whole source zip.

Searched through old SO threads but none answers this direct question. Some say publishing source zip has been discontinued 2.0 onwards.

Is there anyone  who downloaded 2.9.x source and has it available in zip format to download or any place on internet making this available?

Comment: Why not checkout the svn-copy, or use the distributed assembly file?

Comment: I am new with SVN. Installed tortoiseSVN. Now how to pull the sources from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_2/             Thats the version I am looking for.

Comment: ok. could do it all with tortoise ! thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated there's no official zip file for the most recent version. Just get the source from svn and build your own, it takes all of 10 minutes (including downloading and installing tortoisesvn) and I wouldn't download it from any questionable site anyway.

Comment: I am new with SVN. Installed tortoiseSVN. Now how to pull the sources from svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/… Thats the version I am looking for.

Comment: Just right click tortoise and select "SVN checkout.." then set the URL of the repository to https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_2/

Answer (score 0):

As of now [Apache link (svn)](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download.html) does not work

I got the dlls from [NuGet site](http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.net)

You can try [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net) too